# how to install igblast in conda environment

Tags: conda, blast

I'm facing problem installing igblast in conda,

I have tried the commands as in [anaconda/bioconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/igblast)

```
conda install -c bioconda igblast
```

that throws an error when running igblastn

```
error while loading shared libraries: libncbi-vdb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

while the second

```
conda install -c "bioconda/label/cf201901" igblast
```

installed a VERY old version that produced incorrect results

```
igblastn -version
igblastn: 1.0.0
Package: igblast 1.10.0, build Sep  4 2018 11:24:17
```

trying to update did nothing as conda reports all is good! Any idea what to do? I'm trying to avoid manual installation.

PS: couldn't add igblast as a tag to the question due to not having enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bioconda requires the Conda Forge channel to function correctly since that is what is used when packages on Bioconda are built. Try

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda igblast
```

Note that I would strongly advise against installing Bioconda and Conda Forge packages in an Anaconda **base** environment. Instead, create a new environment. Not clear if that applies in this situation.